# Simple onto functions

Tags: functions

Find continuous and onto real functions between the following(if possible)

1. $(0,1)\rightarrow(0,1]$
2. $(0,1]\rightarrow(0,1)$
3. $(0,1) \rightarrow(0,1)\cup(2,3)$

In 1 we can define a function like $f(x)=\sqrt{x-x^2}$. But what about part 2 and 3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For #3 keep in mind the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Anyhow in 3, I cannot define a continuous function.

Comment: @Umakant There is no continuous onto function $f:(0,1)\to (0,1)\cup (2,3)$. Because $(0,1)$ is connected but $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ is not connected.

Comment: @tetori Thanks. Although I figured that part, I am unable to figure out part 2. I don't think such a function exists but cannot say how. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 3, such a function does not exist: The continuous image of a connected set is again connected. Or, more basically: Use the intermediate value theorem.

**Edit**: A modified example works after all.

For 2, take $f \colon (0,1] → (0,1)$ to be given by $f(x) = \tfrac{1}{2}·\big((1-x)·\sin \big(\tfrac{1}{x}\big) + 1\big)$.

Obviously, $∀ x ∈ (0,1]:\quad (1-x)·\sin \big(\tfrac{1}{x}\big) ∈ (-1,1)$, so $f(x) ∈ (0,1)$.

For $k ∈ ℕ$, plugging $\tfrac{π}{2} + 2πk$ and $\tfrac{3π}{2} + 2πk$ into $g \colon [1,∞) → (-1,1),\; x ↦ (1-\tfrac{1}{x})· \sin (x)$ gives you sequences $1 - \tfrac{2}{π + 4πk}$ and $-(1 - \tfrac{2}{3π + 4πk})$, converging to $1$ and $-1$, so by the intermediate value theorem $g$ is surjective.

And therefore so is $f$, which differs from $g$ only by the bijections $[1,∞) → (0,1],\; 1 ↦ \tfrac{1}{x}$ and $(-1,1) → (0,1),\; x ↦ \tfrac{1}{2}(x+1)$.

*Background*: Initially, I suggested this function, which is ill-defined for $x=1$:

> $f \colon (0,1] → (0,1),\, x ↦ (1-x)· \tfrac{1}{2}·\big(\sin \big(\tfrac{1}{x}\big) + 1\big)$

Comment: @ K.Stm. How did you figure out the function for #2.

Comment: @Umakant It doesn’t work! for $x = 1$ you get zero! Maybe this can be corrected.

Comment: Yup I checked that on Mathematica. I don't think such a function exists.

Comment: @UmaKant I was right after all! I just stretched the function too late. (Also, you shouldn’t have taken out my wrong attempt, since there was truth in it.)

Comment: Sorry for that.

Comment: @Umakant Also, to answer how I figured it out: Such a function $f$ has for any $ε > 0$ the image $f([ε,1])$ compactly in $(0,1)$. Therefore on the right side it always misses out a bit on both extremes, $0$ and $1$! So the only chance to reach all $(0,1)$ is on the left side near zero. There it has to reach more and more of $(0,1)$ as it gets closer and closer to zero, so expanding in both directions towards $0$ and towards $1$. This may be achieved by an increasing oscillation. And there I was.

Comment: @Umakant Or another way to think about it: Let $[a,b] = f([ε,1])$. Then any pair of values $x$, $y$ with $0 < x < a$ and $b < y < 1$, assuming $f$ is surjective, must now have preimages in $(0,ε)$. By the intermediate value theorem, this implies $[x,y] ⊂ f((0,ε))$. Since $x$ and $y$ are arbitratry, this means $(0,1) ⊂ f((0,ε))$. Since $ε$ was arbitrary, this means that such an $f$ always has to oscillate at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, differentiable function that maps $(0,1]$ continuously onto $(0,1)$ is $f(x) = ((1-\sqrt{x})\sin(1/x)+1)/2$, which looks like so:

[image]

Comment: That’s what I said. But nice graph! (What software did you use?)

Comment: @K.Stm. Sorry! I didn't even notice that!  I actually took a quick look at tetori's answer and tried to make that happen in a smooth way.  I even started with $1-x$, rather than $1-\sqrt{x}$ but added the root to accentuate the fact that the graph is not quite at 1 then not quite at 0. Well, I better upvote your answer now!

Comment: @ MarkMcClure Thanks a lot. and sorry again @K.Stm.

Comment: @K.Stm. I used Mathematica.

Comment: @Umakant Nah, it’s no problem. I just mean: Generally speaking – you shouldn’t do something like that since there always might be truth or good directions in wrong attempts. I set my answer community wiki to give others the opportunity to fix my solution. In this case, it is best if they can read it directly. (The important thing is that the mistake is clearly denoted.) Anyway, I don’t feel personally attacked or something, so no problem. : — )

Answer (score 0):

Let define $A_{2n}=(2^{-2n},2^{-2n-1})$, $A_{2n+1}=(2^{-2n-1},1-2^{-2n-2})$. Let define $f$ is linear interpolation of $A_0$, $A_1$, $A_2$, $\cdots$.

Then $0<f<1$ by definition, and for every $r\in (0,1)$, and range of line segment between $A_{2n}$ and $A_{2n+1}$ is $[2^{-2n}, 1-2^{-2n-1}]$, and range of line segment between $A_{2n-1}$ and $A_{2n}$ is $[1-2^{-2n}, 2^{-2n-1}]$, so $f:(0,1]\to(0,1)$ is onto.